What's meaning of zero energy reference point in the energy-axis of zero-bias transmission spectrum extracted by sisl.get_sile('systemlabel.TBT.nc')?
I extracted the zero-bias transmission spectrum with respect to energy by the following code:
tbt = sisl.get_sile('systemlabel.TBT.nc')
plt.plot(tbt.E, tbt.transmission(), label='k-averaged');
plt.plot(tbt.E, tbt.transmission(kavg=tbt.kindex([0, 0, 0])), label=r'$\Gamma$'); 
plt.xlabel('Energy [eV]'); plt.ylabel('Transmission'); plt.ylim([0, None]); plt.legend();


What is the meaning of zero energy reference point in the energy-axis of zero-bias transmission spectrum extracted by sisl.get_sile('systemlabel.TBT.nc')? Is it the reference energy level, ER, which typically is the Fermi level from the pure DFT calculation based on the answer Where are chemical potential windows [μR, μL] in the transmission spectra?.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

sisl does not alter the energies, this is exactly the same as the linked question. And NO, the zero energy reference is NOT u=(uL+uR)/2. See point 4 in the referenced link.

Thank you, Sir, your helped me understand my problem better. I should emphasize it is the zero-bias situation.

The answer is still the same, V=uL=uR=0.

Thank you, Sir, I can understand V=uL=uR=0. Is it also the reference energy level, ER, which typically is the Fermi level from the pure DFT calculation?  This is important because I want to use this as a basis to determine the distance from the Fermi level to the bottom of the conduction band and thus determine the size of the Schottky barrier height.

Thank you, Sir, I think the answer is yes.

As a specific example to supplement the previous question Where are chemical potential windows [μR, μL] in the transmission spectra?:
The zero bias transmission spectrum corresponds to zero bias DOS of the device region without any electrodes, and the zero energy reference point in the transmission spectrum is consistent with the fermi energy of the device region.
